# Finding a user account in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, administration, user-accounts

Is there a way to find a particular user account in a database on a SQL Server?

Typically you would add an account to the SQL Server, at which point you can also map the user to multiple databases on that server. As long as no one does anything bad, you can return to the account properties on the server as see the databases the account was mapped to.

However, this linkage can be easily broken, where an account exists in a database, but it does not show up as mapped to that database at the server level. Also, you cannot create an account on the server if it already exists in one of the databases, this is the situation I'm in.

There are 100's of databases and I need to find the one that this users account is in. As far as I know sys.database_principals us unique to each database. Is it possible to do a cross database search for an account and return the database(s) that it exists in?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some helper queries.

declare @returnValue int
EXEC @returnValue = sp_change_users_login 'Update_One', 'SXAUtil', 'SXAUtil'
print '/@returnValue/'
print @returnValue
print ''

```
select * from master..syslogins where name='MyUser001'


select * from  [MyDatabase001]..sysusers where name='MyUser001'


select 1 as 'Match??' , mastSysLogin.sid as mastSysLogin_Sid, localSysLogin.sid as localSysLogin_Sid, mastSysLogin.name as mastSysLogin_Name , localSysLogin.name as localSysLogin_Name from  master..syslogins mastSysLogin join [MyDatabase001]..sysusers localSysLogin on mastSysLogin.sid = localSysLogin.sid
where mastSysLogin.name='MyUser001'
go
```

This procedure is being deprecated I think, but researching it will show some "missing link" informaiton.

```
Use MyDatabase001
GO

declare @returnValue int
EXEC @returnValue = sp_change_users_login 'Update_One', 'MyUser001', 'MyUser001'
print '/@returnValue/'
print @returnValue
print ''
```

Below is a script I wrote to add users to logins and as dbusers and map to some roles.

It uses SQLCMD Mode.  But it is a "over the years" effort as I tried to write code to create users , and it wouldn't throw errors if the user was already added.

```
/*

--SqlCmd Notes:

--Remove comments and space between ":" and "setvar" to run in sqlcmd mode.  

--!!! Checked in code MUST *recomment out* the setvars below !!!  (Putting a space between the ":" and the "setvar" is sufficient)
--      (This is not preferred behavior, the issue has been reported at http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/382007/in-sqlcmd-scripts-setvar-should-have-a-lower-precedence-than-command-line-variable-assignments )


: setvar ErrorOutputFileFromCommandLine "c:\wuwutemp\sqlcommmanderrorfile.txt"
: setvar DBNAME "MyDatabaseName"
: setvar DBUSERNAME "MyDomain\someDomainUserThatExists"

*/




Use [$(DBNAME)]
GO

:Error $(ErrorOutputFileFromCommandLine) 





declare @databaseName varchar(64)
select @databaseName = db_name()


print '/@databaseName/'
print @databaseName
print ''

set nocount on


declare @CONST_DB_DATAREADER_ROLE varchar(64)
select @CONST_DB_DATAREADER_ROLE = 'db_datareader'

declare @CONST_DB_BACKUPOPERATOR_ROLE varchar(64)
select @CONST_DB_BACKUPOPERATOR_ROLE = 'db_backupoperator'


declare @UserNameHolder table ( IdentityID int identity(101,1) , DatabaseName varchar(128) , LoginName varchar(256) , MassagedLoginName varchar(264) , RoleName varchar(64) not null , AlreadyProcessed bit default 0 not null )

INSERT INTO @UserNameHolder ( DatabaseName , LoginName , RoleName ) values ( '$(DBNAME)' , '$(DBUSERNAME)' , @CONST_DB_DATAREADER_ROLE )
--INSERT INTO @UserNameHolder ( DatabaseName , LoginName , RoleName ) values ( '$(DBNAME)' , '$(DBUSERNAME)' , @CONST_DB_BACKUPOPERATOR_ROLE )





/* Below this line is "common logic code"   */








Update @UserNameHolder Set MassagedLoginName = LoginName

    /*
        sp_grantlogin does NOT like brackets around a domain/user
        example : EXEC sp_grantlogin @loginame = N'[MyDomain\MyUser]'
        The "massaging" below is a work around to this issue
    */

Update @UserNameHolder Set MassagedLoginName = RIGHT(MassagedLoginName , LEN(MassagedLoginName) -1 ) where LEN(MassagedLoginName)>0 AND LEFT( MassagedLoginName,1)='[' 
Update @UserNameHolder Set MassagedLoginName = LEFT( MassagedLoginName , LEN(MassagedLoginName) -1 ) where LEN(MassagedLoginName)>0 AND RIGHT(MassagedLoginName,1)=']'

/* Use a iffy rule to figure out NT Names */
--Update @UserNameHolder Set IsNTName = 1 where LEN(LoginName)>0 AND LEFT( LoginName,1)='[' AND RIGHT(LoginName,1)=']'

-- public is built in, do not process it
Update @UserNameHolder Set AlreadyProcessed = 1 where UPPER(LoginName) = UPPER('public')


select * from @UserNameHolder



declare @CurrentIdentityID int
declare @CurrentLoginName varchar(256)
declare @CurrentMassagedLoginName varchar(256)
declare @CurrentDatabaseName varchar(64)
--declare @CurrentIsNTName bit
declare @CurrentRoleName varchar(64)

declare @sp_grantdbaccess_return_value_total int
select @sp_grantdbaccess_return_value_total = 0



declare @sp_addrolemember_return_value_total int
select @sp_addrolemember_return_value_total = 0


while exists (select null from @UserNameHolder where AlreadyProcessed = 0)
begin
        select @CurrentIdentityID = (select top 1 IdentityID from @UserNameHolder where AlreadyProcessed = 0)

        print '@CurrentIdentityID'
        print @CurrentIdentityID
        print ''

        select  @CurrentLoginName = ( select top 1 LoginName from @UserNameHolder where IdentityID = @CurrentIdentityID )
        select  @CurrentMassagedLoginName = ( select top 1 MassagedLoginName from @UserNameHolder where IdentityID = @CurrentIdentityID )
        select  @CurrentDatabaseName = ( select top 1 DatabaseName from @UserNameHolder where IdentityID = @CurrentIdentityID )
        --select  @CurrentIsNTName = ( select top 1 IsNTName from @UserNameHolder where IdentityID = @CurrentIdentityID )       
        select  @CurrentRoleName = ( select top 1 RoleName from @UserNameHolder where IdentityID = @CurrentIdentityID )     




        print '@CurrentLoginName'
        print @CurrentLoginName
        print ''
        print '@CurrentMassagedLoginName'
        print @CurrentMassagedLoginName
        print ''
        print '@CurrentDatabaseName'
        print @CurrentDatabaseName
        print ''    
        --print '@CurrentIsNTName'
        --print @CurrentIsNTName
        --print ''  
        print '@CurrentRoleName'
        print @CurrentRoleName
        print ''            


        if(1=1)  /* 1=1 is helpful while debugging, set to 1=2 to exclude */
        begin           

            --  select name, loginname from master.dbo.syslogins where loginname = @currentLoginName and isntname = 1)
            if not exists (select null from master.dbo.syslogins where UPPER(loginname) = UPPER(@CurrentLoginName) ) -- and isntname = 1)
            begin
                print 'About to execute sp_grantlogin for user:'
                print @CurrentMassagedLoginName
                EXEC sp_grantlogin @loginame = @CurrentMassagedLoginName
                print ''
                print ''
                print 'About to execute sp_defaultdb for user:'
                print @CurrentMassagedLoginName
                EXEC sp_defaultdb @loginame = @CurrentMassagedLoginName , @defdb = @CurrentDatabaseName
                print ''
                print ''
            end
            else
            begin
                print 'NOT EXECUTED : sp_grantlogin'
                print 'NOT EXECUTED : sp_defaultdb'             
            end

        end

            ----------------------------------------



            declare @sp_grantdbaccess_return_value int
            declare @sp_change_users_login_return_value int

            declare @needToRunThisIteration bit 
            select @needToRunThisIteration = 0


            -- declare @currentLoginName varchar(64)

            if(1=1)  /* 1=1 is helpful while debugging, set to 1=2 to exclude */
            begin
                if not exists 
                    (
                        select * from master.dbo.syslogins ml inner join dbo.sysusers
                        su on ml.sid = su.sid where 
                            su.uid < 6382
                            and
                            UPPER(ml.name) = UPPER(@CurrentMassagedLoginName) 

                    )

                    begin
                            if not exists 
                                (
                                    /* NOTE, this database name variable must be updated if copying/pasting 'common logic code' between database deployments  (NEED_TO_REPLACE_A_VALUE) */
                                    select * from master.dbo.syslogins ml Where
                                        UPPER(ml.name) = UPPER(@CurrentMassagedLoginName) 
                                        and UPPER(ml.dbname) = UPPER('$(DBNAME)')

                                )

                                begin
                                        select @needToRunThisIteration = 1
                                end
                    end


                    if not exists 
                        (
                            /* NOTE, this database name variable must be updated if copying/pasting 'common logic code' between database deployments  (NEED_TO_REPLACE_A_VALUE) */
                            select * FROM [$(DBNAME)]..sysusers su Where
                                UPPER(su.name) = UPPER(@CurrentMassagedLoginName) 
                        )

                        begin
                                select @needToRunThisIteration = 1
                        end                 


                        /*
                                Debug

                                select dbname , loginname , * from master.dbo.syslogins ml where dbname != 'master' order by 1 , 2

                                select * FROM TPA2Report..sysusers su



                        */                  

                declare @stringNameMatchesButNotSid bit
                select @stringNameMatchesButNotSid = 0

                IF EXISTS   (
                                SELECT dbUsers.name as NameToFix , *
                                FROM sys.sysusers dbUsers 
                                join sys.syslogins sqlServerLogins on UPPER(dbUsers.name) = UPPER(sqlServerLogins.name)
                                WHERE dbUsers.sid != sqlServerLogins.sid 
                                and UPPER(dbUsers.name) = UPPER(@CurrentMassagedLoginName)
                            )
                    begin
                            select @stringNameMatchesButNotSid = 1
                    end



                if (@needToRunThisIteration!=0)

                    begin

                        if @stringNameMatchesButNotSid = 0
                            begin

                                    print 'About to execute sp_grantdbaccess for user:'
                                    print @CurrentMassagedLoginName
                                    exec @sp_grantdbaccess_return_value = sp_grantdbaccess @CurrentMassagedLoginName
                                    print ''
                                    print '@sp_grantdbaccess_return_value'
                                    print @sp_grantdbaccess_return_value
                                    print ''                

                                    select @sp_grantdbaccess_return_value_total = @sp_grantdbaccess_return_value_total + @sp_grantdbaccess_return_value
                            end
                        else
                            begin
                                    /*  There is a mismatched "sid" issue, but with the same names.  This will address the issue.  */                                   

                                    print 'About to execute sp_change_users_login for user:'
                                    print @CurrentMassagedLoginName
                                    EXEC @sp_change_users_login_return_value = sp_change_users_login @Action='update_one', @UserNamePattern=@CurrentMassagedLoginName,@LoginName=@CurrentMassagedLoginName;                     
                                    print ''
                                    print '@sp_change_users_login_return_value'
                                    print @sp_change_users_login_return_value
                                    print ''                                        

                            end
                    end
            end



            -------------------------------------------------------                     


            declare @sp_addrolemember_return_value int

            if(1=1)  /* 1=1 is helpful while debugging, set to 1=2 to exclude */
            begin

                if not exists
                (
                SELECT null --, role_principal_id, member_principal_id, princ1.name AS
                role_name, princ2.name As member_name
                FROM sys.database_role_members AS S LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals AS
                princ1 ON S.role_principal_id = princ1.principal_id AND princ1.type = 'R'
                LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals AS princ2 ON S.member_principal_id =
                princ2.principal_id AND princ2.type IN ('S', 'U')
                WHERE princ1.name = @CurrentRoleName and UPPER(princ2.name) = UPPER(@CurrentMassagedLoginName)
                )
                begin


                    print 'About to execute sp_grantdbaccess for user:'
                    print @CurrentMassagedLoginName
                    print 'For the role:'
                    print @CurrentRoleName
                    exec @sp_addrolemember_return_value = sp_addrolemember @CurrentRoleName, @CurrentMassagedLoginName
                    print ''
                    print '@sp_addrolemember_return_value'
                    print @sp_addrolemember_return_value
                    print ''

                    select @sp_addrolemember_return_value_total = @sp_addrolemember_return_value_total + @sp_addrolemember_return_value

                end

            end



        Update @UserNameHolder Set AlreadyProcessed = 1 Where IdentityID = @CurrentIdentityID
end




print '/@sp_grantdbaccess_return_value_total/'
print @sp_grantdbaccess_return_value_total

print '/@sp_addrolemember_return_value_total/'
print @sp_addrolemember_return_value_total




GO
```